# WebService client replaces number 1 with _x0031_ in string

Tags: c#, web-services, client

I am doing a client in c# for a webservice in java
the problem is that the .net serializer when a string starts with
the number 1 it replaces the number and put a "_ **x0031_**"

```
var client = new wsProcesa();
var transito = new sv.test.registrarTest{
  NO_Test = "SV000001"
  NO_Licencia = "110110000034"
} ;
client.procesa(transito);
```

when i check the xml on the java side or if i serialize the registrarTest Class 
i receive

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<registrarTest>
  <NO_Test>SV000001</NO_Test>
  <NO_Licencia>_x0031_10110000034</NO_Licencia> 
</registrarTest>
```

Comment: 0x0031 is the UFT-8 for "1". curious why its converting if its only doing so to the first char.

Comment: @FrankThomas: almost seems as if the first character of that string just isn't allowed to be a number ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the generated class because the field was marked as DataType = "NCName"

i remove the tag in the generated class and now is working 
and i'm going to remove the tag in the xsd on the java side